# How to control background music

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app with a background music and the music starts when the first view (`INTROViewController`) appears (it is implemented in `viewDidLoad`). I have created a settings page (`OPTIONSViewController`) where I have implemented a switch to turn the music on and off. In `OPTIONSViewController` I have created an instance of `INTROViewController` where all the audio files and the commands to play and stop the music are defined. I don't get any errors but it seems the instance is not able to control the music at all, which continues playing. What am i doing wrong? Cheers

Comment: update some code from where you are accessing the properties of the introviewcontroller coz it's like impossible to trace your bug from the statements only.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can have just one AVPlayer on your `AppDelegate`.

Declare it like a property, and then u can get this player from all your application 
with something like this:

`yourAppDelegate* appDele= (yourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`

`AVPlayer * tempPlayer = [appDele yourPlayer];`

This should fix your problem :D